# Lace cookies TOO thin?

Tags: baking, cookies, candy, thickness

I tried to make https://myjerusalemkitchen.com/2011/05/22/dark-chocolate-almond-orange-lace-cookies-florentines/ (I used bee honey not date honey) and they taste GREAT, **but they did not come out right. They basically came out as a sheet of caramel, VERY thin.**

I tried letting the "dough" cool longer before scooping out of pan and on to cookie sheet. I also tried decreasing the time in the oven. Using an actual teaspoon measure, 8 of these (3 rows: 3, 2, 3) with at least 3 inches between each blob, covered virtually the whole pan.

Anyone have a better recipe or suggestions?

## Recipe

### Ingredients

- 1/2 c brown sugar
- 2 tblsp butter
- 1 tsp vanilla extract
- 2 tblsp milk
- 1/4 c date honey (or regular honey)
- 1/3 c all-purpose flour
- 1/2 c almonds; coarsely ground
- 1/2 tsp cinnamon
- 1 heaping tsp orange, zested
- 1/2 c dark chocolate (for dipping)

### Tips:

1. You must follow the order here. I have accidentally added the almond mixture at the wrong stage and the cookies will not spread.
2. Cool your tray with water each time you remove it from the oven (it will not warp your tray) or get three trays handy because if you drop your batter onto a heated tray the cookies will start to spread instantly and will be oddly-shaped.
3. If you end up with any oddly shaped ones, just take some scissors and cut the edges before the cookies have completely cooled down.

### Directions:

1. Preheat your oven to 350 F
2. line two baking trays with parchment paper; set aside.
3. Bring the butter, sugar, milk, vanilla, and honey to a boil, stirring continuously.
4. Once it reaches a rolling boil, wait one minute and then remove from the heat.
5. Now, grab a bowl and mix the flour, almonds, cinnamon and orange zest together, slowly adding them to the wet mixture and making sure everything is incorporated well.
6. Let sit for about 20 minutes or until the mixture is cool enough to be handled, even though you won’t be handling it.
7. If the mixture is stiff when you return to it, warm it up over a low flame for a minute or two.
8. Drop teaspoon-sized balls onto your parchment paper, leaving about three inches space between each of the cookies because they will spread a lot.
9. Create a double-boiler to melt the chocolate or melt it in the microwave.
10. Leave them to cook for 6-8 minutes.

    - If you want them more like toffee brittle leave them in on the longer end.
    - I like mine slightly chewy in the center and crispy on the outside.
11. Once the centers are bubbling and they are a goldeny-brown color, remove them from the oven.
12. Immediately remove the parchment paper from the tray and let them cool on the counter.
13. After about three-five more minutes, you’ll be able to remove them from the parchment paper without a problem. Any sooner and they’ll still be soft and likely tear.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Seasoned Advice. Rather than having a link to your recipe, it would be better to include it in the actual question.

Comment: @DanielGriscom edited to include the recipe

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer?  I used to make an oatmeal lace cookie (I think it was from the Fannie Farmer cookbook), and I remember if being *very* sensitive to temperature changes ... basically how quickly the butter melts and spreads before it's cooked to the point of setting up.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think that adding a bit more flour to the mix would help them be thicker. The trouble is exactly how much. When I learned how to make creme brulee it took me at least a dozen attempts to get it perfect but once I figured it out it has stuck with me.

Comment: 1/3 US cup is about 16tsp, so if it were me and the first batch came out too thin, I'd mix in another teaspoon or so of flour (less than 10% of the original amount) and then try another test ... but if I were to remake it from scratch, I'd reduce the amount of milk.